# Google Scripts Dependent Drop Down List - NOT WORKING

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

so I was following a google sheet - Dependent Drop Down List tutorial which can be viewed here:

```
 *https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s-I8Z4nTDak&t=45s*
```

---

I have been through the tutorial 3 times now and have tried a number of things... BUT I am still having trouble with getting the script to work

The Problem: On the sheet "master" when I select an item from column D (labeled - category)  the dependent dropdown list for column E appears **BUT** does not show the corresponding options that match. Instead, the dependent dropdown list just shows a blank??

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My Google Sheet:

*https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DOF_CECC_c28dmIhdaYaG0KBn8fqdZ-qqGoiTxEMZo8/edit?usp=sharing*

Script Code:

```
var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("master");
var wsOptions = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("options");
var options = wsOptions.getRange(2,3,wsOptions.getLastRow()-1,4).getValues();



function myfunction() {

  var list = ["a","b","g"];
  var cell = ws.getRange("E2");
  applyValidationToCell(list,cell);

}






function onEdit(e){
  var activeCell = e.range;
  var val = activeCell.getValue();
  var r = activeCell.getRow();
  var c = activeCell.getColumn();
  var wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getName();
  if(wsName == "master" && c === 4 && r > 1){
    var filteredOptions = options.filter(function(o){ return o[2] === val });
    var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){ return o[3] });
    var cell = ws.getRange(r, 5);
    applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
  }
}






function applyValidationToCell(list,cell){

  var rule = SpreadsheetApp
  .newDataValidation()
  .requireValueInList(list)
  .setAllowInvalid(false)
  .build();

  cell.setDataValidation(rule);


}
```

Comment: I made a copy of your Spreadsheet and the script worked successfully, when I select any value in drop-down D a drop-down in C is created with the different options for each case. Try running onEdit function directly from the script so you can grant the permissions.